# How to make requests work with debugging?

Tags: websocket, python-requests, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I have the following that does not work.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://example.com')
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'example.png'})
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

It shows something like this.

```
...
[D:pyppeteer.connection.Connection] RECV: {"id":18,"result":{}}
DEBUG:websockets.client:< TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetDestroyed","params":{"t...B9D141622A1A8C504495"}}' [92 bytes]
DEBUG:websockets.client:= connection is CLOSING
DEBUG:websockets.client:> CLOSE 1000 (OK) [2 bytes]
DEBUG:websockets.client:< TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetDestroyed","params":{"t...1792091509A69FA2AACC"}}' [92 bytes]
DEBUG:websockets.client:! failing connection with code 1006
DEBUG:websockets.client:= connection is CLOSED
```

If I delete the following lines, it works.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

What is the correct way to show the requests sent in this example code yet still make sure the code works?

Also, the ws requests are not printed completely (you see "..."). How to show the ws requests completely.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to see all the logs for `DEBUG:websockets.client` and want to avoid all others?

Comment: I updated it. Is it clear now?

Comment: The "..." maybe are coming due to some IDE specifications, when you run on simple termical/console/cmd you will get complete log,
`DEBUG:websockets.protocol:client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"0B3029F9B4D11B9A145C6774A4969D01","type":"page","title":"about:blank","url":"about:blank","attached":false,"browserContextId":"2A8C00899542F60F21DE947344663899"}}}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)`

Comment: I am not sure what mean. Could you show the complete code on how to print ws requests completely? @FaizanAlHassan